# osm2po: access values of maxweight tag

Tags: osm2po

What is a best way to access osm's maxweight tag value to be able to use it in edge router?

Basically my goal is to overwrite EdgeRouter's calcEdgeCost and check there if given edgeIdx has maxweight tag and if yes then act upon value of that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you'll need a place where you can store this value.
Usually this is done by overwriting the DefaultWayTagResolver and
to modify the "flags" which is a user defined 32-Bits Integer.
The default impl looks like this:

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public int getFlags() {
    int flags = this.accessAllowedFlags & ~this.accessDeniedFlags;
    // TODO merge or return your maxweight here
    return flags;
}
```

Overwrite the Router

```
@Override
public int[] findPath(Graph graph, int sourceId, int targetId,
        float maxCost, Properties params) {
   this.graph = graph; // fetch a reference to the graph
   return super.findPath(graph, sourceId, targetId, maxCost, params);
}


@Override
protected double calcEdgeCost(int edgeIdx) {
    int flags = this.graph.getEdgeFlags()[edgeIdx];
    // TODO Analyze your flags here
    return this.edgeCosts[edgeIdx];
}
```

Don't call the standard Graph-Constructor. Instead use this one here:

```
Graph graph = new Graph(graphFile, new Log(), Graph.SUPPORT_EDGEFLAGS | Graph.SUPPORT_LATLON);
```